# Where is the start up page defined in mono for android

Tags: xamarin.android

I need to change the start up page for my monodriod app? how can i change it to a different activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Guides/Working_with_AndroidManifest.xml

See "Launchable from Application Chooser".